# Why was my question “ Kiruv and outreach arguments” closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

Why was this question [Kiruv and outreach arguments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/137608/759) which was originally closed, then re opened, closed again and all the comments were moved to private chat rooms?

Answer (score 2):

An [earlier version](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/57952168-a200-41f3-8afa-f5bcdda11173/view-source) of the post was originally closed by the community as "Opinion-based". Two extant (at this time) comments indicate a possible rationale for this closure:

> To every person a different argument works, and for some no argument. There isn't a one-size-fits-all argument. –
> Harel13
> Oct 22 at 4:58

> Asking for the most effective is likely to be closed as it is nearly impossible to measure. You could possibly ask for some of the arguments, or since it is a complex topic, you could ask for resources discussing the topic. Entire books have been written on it –
> mbloch
> Oct 22 at 6:17

You edited the post, and it was re-opened by the community.

Subsequently, I reviewed the post and closed it as "Needs more focus." I believe that I was taking into account the point made in one of the above comments that "Entire books have been written on it." As the FAQ page for [standard closure reasons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) says, "If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format."

The basic reason for pushing comment streams to chatrooms is indicated in the notice that gets posted when that happens: "Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on Mi Yodeya Meta, or in Mi Yodeya Chat."